# Ruby: repeating a method n times all in one line

Tags: ruby

Suppose we have a method that returns a random string :

```
def return_random
  "random generated string #{Time.now}"
end
```

How to create a new string that is an addition of n times of return_random.

Exemple :

`new_string = return_random + return_random + ... + return_random [n times]`

**Edit**: Using `return_random * n` won't work because it's copying the string n times and not generating new ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do it:

```
new_string = n.times.collect { return_random }.inject(:+)
```